# How do I access ngFor variable inside other ngFor?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

Following code would be used to show the details of the users. As of now we have only one user and three permission. The array defined as follows:

```
1) Users  = [{'FirstName':'John','permission':['masters','transactions']}] 
2) permissions = ['masters','transactions','settings']
```

The first for loop iterates the users and second, the permissions.
The logic is, if the permission from permissions exists in users permission then mark the checkbox as true.

```
<div  *ngFor="let user of users">  

  <label> user.FirstName </label>

  <ol>
    <li *ngFor="let permission in permissions">
      <input type="checkbox" checked="user.permission.indexOf(permission)"
    </li>
  </ol>

</div>
```

But it says

> Cannot read property 'Permissions' of undefined

How can I access the variable in nested for ?

Answer (score 3):

As `permissions` is array you should use `of` not `in` , there is no such thing like `in` this latest angular version  :

Change :

```
<li *ngFor="let permission in permissions">
```

to

```
<li *ngFor="let permission of permissions">
```

---

You code should look like this :

```
<div  *ngFor="let user of Users">  
  <label> {{ user.FirstName }} </label>
  <ol>
    <li *ngFor="let permission of permissions">
      {{ permission }}
      <input type="checkbox" [checked]="user.permission.indexOf(permission)> -1 ? true : false">
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-use-permission-demo)